# Error of undefined variable in GUI in SCILAB

Tags: scilab

I am making GUI in scilab ,my code is :-

```
///first push button
function file_open_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  file_open  here
Image = imread(path);
//handles.Image=Image;
figure();ShowColorImage(Image,'mixer');//show image
I1G=rgb2gray(Image);
ShowImage(I1G,'mixer');
handles.I1G=I1G;
//handles= getcallbackobject(f.figure_id);
endfunction

///second push button
function select_ROI1_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  select_ROI1  here
rect1 = rubberbox();xrect(rect1);///disp(rect1);
handles.rect1=rect1;
endfunction

///Third pushbutton
function Reverse_Yaxis_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  Reverse_Yaxis  here
//handles.I1G=findobj('Tag','file_open');
//I1G=handles.I1G;
imheight=size(handles.I1G,'r');//image height
rect1(2)=imheight-rect1(2);//reverse y axis coordinate
endfunction
```

it shows following **error:**

> !--error 4  Undefined variable: I1G at line 3 of function
>   Reverse_Yaxis_callback called by :    %oldgcbo = gcbo; end;gcbo =
>   getcallbackobject(312);Reverse_Yaxis_callback(handles);if
>   exists("%oldgcbo") then gcbo = %oldgcbo; else clear gcbo; end while
>   executing a callback

How can I solve this?

Comment: Before calling `Reverse_Yaxis_callback(handles)` try to check whether `handles.I1G` exist: type `handles.I1G` into the consol. Does it return the I1G matrix?

Comment: I have solved this problem by assigning global variables,but how to define rect1(2) (as an array or as a pointer), because it is not defined as global variables?